# Could not find default endpoint element that references contract?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, rest, wcf-rest

I am a beginner to `WCF service`. I create a Wcf rest service. This works fine if i browse it.

Then i added a new web application and add reference of that service. The service is loaded correctly. But when I check the web.config it doesnot contain any detail about service model and its empty. I implemented and built and run the solution, it breaks and give this error:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'ProductRestService.IProductRESTService' in the ServiceModel client
>   configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was
>   found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching
>   this contract could be found in the client element.

My service webconfig is as:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService1.ProductRestService"
               behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="ProductRestService" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IProductRESTService"
              behaviorConfiguration="web"></endpoint>
    </service>
    </services>
      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

and I implemeted  it for testing as:

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
  {
       ProductRestService.ProductRESTServiceClient pro = new ProductRestService.ProductRESTServiceClient("ProductRestService");
       var prodcuts = pro.GetProductList();
       GridView1.DataSource = prodcuts;
       GridView1.DataBind();
  }
```

and client web.config is empty as:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

**How do I resolve this help!!!**

Answer (score 2):

Add Following code in your web.config file and it will fix the problem,

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="WebHttpBinding_IProductRESTService" />
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://{DomainName}/ProductRestService/" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBinding_IProductRESTService" contract="WcfService1.IProductRESTService" name="WebHttpBinding_IProductRESTService" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```